# Cannot connect telegram bot with stripe payments

Tags: stripe-payments, telegram, telegram-bot

Ive been trying to connect my telegram bot with stripe test bot, but it wont succeeding , the bot shows

Couldn't connect Stripe account, OAuth has failed. Please try again later.

My stripe account is fully verified and live

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: iam trying to make a telegram invoice bot to collect payment, to do that i need to connect my bot with the stripe test bot, to collect payment, but when i try to do it stripe test bot saying oauth has been failed, this is my problem , my stripe account is fully activated